# Set image runtime in VisualBrush with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, visualbrush

actually I set an image took from the resources at designtime into the **xaml** file like this:

```
<Button Click="btnLogin_Click" Name="btnLogin">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Name="recLogin">
            <Rectangle.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="White" />
            </Rectangle.Resources>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_user}" x:Name="brushLogin" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text=" login" Name="txbLogin" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

and works fine. But *(is a login button)* I wish that when the user do a login, the image on the button *(inside a rectangle)* will be changed..

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` to change the image when a property updates in your model.

In this example the boolean value `IsLoggedIn` is changed which in turn changes the image.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="125.078" Width="236.441" Name="UI" >
    <Window.Resources>

        <VisualBrush x:Key="Loggedin">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Image Source="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-basic/32/Ok-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>

        <VisualBrush x:Key="NotLoggedin">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Image Source="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-basic/32/Close-2-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <Button Click="btnLogin_Click" Name="btnLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="94" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="63,26,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Name="recLogin">
                    <Rectangle.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="White" />
                    </Rectangle.Resources>
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource NotLoggedin}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoggedIn}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Loggedin}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Text=" login" Name="txbLogin" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isLoggedIn;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get { return _isLoggedIn; }
        set { _isLoggedIn = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoggedIn"); }
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsLoggedIn = !IsLoggedIn;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
 }
```

**Note:** I just used online images as I dont have your ressources, you can change to suit your needs

Result:

IsLoggedIn = false;
[image]
IsLoggedIn = true;
[image]

Comment: thankyou!!, I have another little question: in my xaml I'm using a `ResourceDictionary`... that create a conflict for the `<VisualBrush x:Key="Loggedin">` and the other...

Comment: Does the `ResourceDictionary` contain any resourses with the same key? You should be able to use any name you want,

Comment: here is my resource:     `
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />`

Comment: `
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Red.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/myProject;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>    
`

Comment: Just try renaming them the to somthing else, one of those xaml files must have the same key names somewhere

Comment: but what name? seems different

Comment: Change `Loggedin` to `Loggedin1` and `NotLoggedin` to `NotLoggedin1` and see if it helps

Comment: also with loggedin1..

http://screencast.com/t/XlDLZHsQIIRR

the line #17 is:

`</ResourceDictionary>`

and the next line is the new line:
`<VisualBrush x:Key="Loggedin1">`