# How can I change the StaticResource used in a VisualBrush from code behind in response to the correct user input?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I have a rectangle with the fill set to an icon from the  icon set that comes with [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)

Here's the code

```
<Rectangle x:Name="urlIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="448,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
       <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_warning}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

In the XAML design I have a URL box that gets user input web address. In the code behind, I check if the web address is reachable, if it is, then I'd like to change the Static Resource to another icon "appbar_check"

Here's the event method for the URL box. urlExists is another method that does the checking of the url.

```
private void urlBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    String url = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

    if (urlExists(url))
    {
        //change icon
     }
 }
```

Comment: Look at [this][1] stack overflow question. Looks like your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819872/set-image-runtime-in-visualbrush-with-c-sharp

Comment: @VibhoreTanwer - I looked at it but it looked more complex and different from what I needed. But the answer below works.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the resource to fill the rectangle as below

```
urlIcon.Fill = new VisualBrush() { Visual = (Visual)Resources["appbar_check"] };
```

also since your resources are UIElements then inorder to use them multiple places you need to set  `<Canvas x:Shared="false" >` on the canvas resource in order to return a new resource everytime you ask. Otherwise it will give an error that the visual is already child of some other control.

Comment: This works the first time but removes the icon when the event fires a second time and this line is executed second time onwards. There is just white space there. Any ideas?

Comment: can you check if Visual property of visual brush is set on second time execution?

Comment: Not exactly sure if I know how to check since I'm fairly new at it, but I stopped the debugger at the line just after second execution of the solution above and navigated to urlIcon->Fill->Visual and I copied the row and it is "Visual {System.Windows.Controls.Canvas} System.Windows.Media.Visual {System.Windows.Controls.Canvas}
"

Comment: can you share xaml for appbar_check?

Comment: <ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Canvas Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" x:Key="appbar_check">
        <Path Width="23.9999" Height="19.9999" Canvas.Left="12.0001" Canvas.Top="14.0001" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 15,21L 22,28L 32.9999,14.0001L 35.9999,17.0001L 22,34L 12.0001,24L 15,21 Z " />
    </Canvas></ResourceDictionary>

Comment: try setting <Canvas x:Shared="false" > on the canvas resource

Comment: Your're a savior! That works but no idea why since these icons come with the UI package. Can you explain what actually was happening and maybe edit your answer to reflect this change too.

Answer (score 1):

As I am on learning curve of WPF I am not sure of the syntax.
But you can try something like this.

```
urlIcon.Fill(new VisualBrush(...))
```

May this help you or give you an idea

Comment: Haha, I'm completely new to C#/WPF too, hence such a simple question but this got me rolling in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of use, you might better use DynamicResource.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this? How would I use this though since the package lists out the syntax and it uses StaticResource

Comment: You mean you can't change it from StaticResource?

Comment: idk, I'm new to C#. But on the page it instructions say "StaticResource" - http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#icons. Would calling it DynamicResource work?