# Styling a button in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a style for some buttons, at first I made one style for the buttons but then I needed an icon in them so i put the icon in the style.

However that is not the way to go, I can't get the icon in the button but out of the style.

code in style:

```
<Style x:Name="stlBtnOpen" x:Key="stlBtnOpen" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                  <Border x:Name="borderBtnOpen" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent">
                      <Grid Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Margin="6">
                          <Grid.OpacityMask>
                              <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_folder}"/>
                          </Grid.OpacityMask>
                      </Grid>
                  </Border>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       //some events
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
</Style>
```

code in element:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnOpen" Click="btnOpen_Click">
      <Border x:Name="borderBtnOpen" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent">
           <Grid Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Margin="6">
                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                   <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_folder}"/>
                </Grid.OpacityMask>
           </Grid>
       </Border>
</Button>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using your style on your button. Why is an icon in a style "not the way to go"?

Comment: Oh no i see... that is a misunderstanding... the style is how i did it first, that works but then i tried placing the icon (in the visualBrush) in the button itself, the second piece of code.
and isn't the idea of a style to be able to use it on multiple buttons? I want to use the style for about 5 different buttons but all with a different icon on them.

Answer (score 2):

*Did you try to put the image in the grid you put in you button's content :

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnOpen" Click="btnOpen_Click">
      <Border x:Name="borderBtnOpen" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent">
           <Grid Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Margin="6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_folder}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Textblock Grid.Column="1"/>
           </Grid>
       </Border>
</Button>
```

Got that from memory, but it shouldn't be too far from what you need (you might also replace the `grid` with a `stackpanel` that would reduce the boilerplate from the columns definitions)

Ah and don't forget to put something into the textblock if you want to have something in your button :)

**EDIT** : 
Well this IS working for me, but there are a coupe of issues inherent to using a brush to fill another object.

But first here is the **EXACT** working markup

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnOpen"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Click="">
            <Border x:Name="borderBtnOpen"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="10">
                <Grid Margin="6"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Width="20px">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="bonjour"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There are 2 issues here :

- The Border will not extend itself to the button size (you can see it if you force a larger width than what the button really needs)
- You will have to manually define the rectangle's size (the brush only fill and does not define it's size) or else, you will have a rectangle with a 0px size which is effectively non existent on screen

For the border issue, you might want to check out what the OP of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717937/i-broke-the-textbox/35718019) did (linking here because the related documentation is also inked)

**EDIT2**

Changed the above code so that the rectangle can be visible when the `Border` is large enough (you can still refer to the linked question for the border issue)

Comment: the icon is not a image, it is in the VisualBrush, that way i can change the color easily without having to make many different icons

Comment: Then change the `Image` to a `Rectangle` and check this question out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819872/set-image-runtime-in-visualbrush-with-c-sharp. You'll also be able to remove the `Grid.OpacityMask`

Comment: @WimVanLaer Edited the code snippet, should be better :)

Comment: it doesn't work, i get a nice rectangle button with a cirle inside

Comment: @WimVanLaer see the edit, I found the problem and potential solutions

Comment: ok thanks, is there no way to automaticly expand the rectangle to the border of the button?

Comment: Didn't have the time to check that out, i'll see if I can find something today :)

Comment: Got something but it is dependant on fixing the border behaviour, which is covered in the question I linked :)