# I broke the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am making a wpf form(moved from winform a couple days ago), and i wanted to customize my textbox. I got the textbox to behave how i want it to, but now i cant give it input, and it does not respond at all when i click it. I think i broke it, anyways here is my code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="White">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF497AB4"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2E2E2E"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="OrangeRed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

So what am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem comes from the Template setter, getting a project up for testing that :)

Comment: Check that MSDN article out : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.110).aspx I think you forgot some things in your `ControlTemplate` which is by the way the section of your style making you unable to interact withe the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Scrollviewer to your template, like this:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
     <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
</Border>
```

You've got some example templates [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.85).aspx)

The problem was that the template didn't have a ContentHost, so it would not render the contents. To add a ContentHost, you should add an element named *"PART_ContentHost"* as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753930(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Wow, now I'd like to know why adding a scrollviewer in the border made the textbox work oO (I got a hunch but I'd like to be sure)

Comment: @Sidewinder94 see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753930(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks ;) You should add this to your answer to make it a better quality one ^^